# Grails 3 serverURL in application.yml

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

I'm trying to set the serverURL per environment in application.yml as follows:

```
environments:
    development:
        grails:
            serverURL: http://localhost:8089
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create
            url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tests
            username: postgress
            password: rootass
```

But it doesn't work - when I do `run-app`it still runs on 8080. Also, how do I set the app name or context name so when I do `run-app` it's like  http://localhost:8089/vis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
server:
    port: 8089
```

You can add contextPath at the same level as port if need be e.g.

```
server:
    port: 8089
    contextPath: '/myApp'
```

Should be accessible at http://localhost:8089/myApp

Comment: if I deploy to example.com, how do I specify is example.com/myApp?

Comment: I personally use apache & set ServerName in httpd.conf, so in your case in would be `example.com` then with the contextPath as set above your app would be accessible at example.com/myApp

Comment: That cannot be used in controller